# How can I change the way coupons applies in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I am using woo-commerce and have 2 restrictions for coupons:
*minimum value* and *maximum value*

When the total value of the cart is either lower than the *minimum value* or higher than the *maximum value*, the coupon won't be applied.

Regarding this, I would like to alter this functionality, and only apply a coupon when the total value of the cart exceeds the *maximum value*. I would also like to apply the discount on only the amount of *maximum value*, not on the whole cart.

Lets look at on an example:

> If the *maximum value* of the coupon is 100$ and has a 10% discount,
>   while the total value of a cart is 200$, then after applying the
>   coupon, the whole cart should cost 190$ and not 180$.

Summarized: where can I change the functionality of coupons to work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found that :)

this filter:

`woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount`

more info at:

`woocommerce/includes/class-wc-coupon.php //Line 597`

Function: `get_discount_amount`